# What is the material design guideline for placeholder images while loading from the network?

Tags: material-design, image, placeholder

I couldn't find any guideline for this in the [spec](https://material.io/design/components/image-lists.html#behavior).

Answer (score 4):

There's a brief mention of this on the [page about launch screens](https://material.io/design/communication/launch-screen.html#placeholder-ui):

> Placeholder elements, with subtle animation, should be displayed in
>   locations where content will load. Placeholder elements should remain
>   positioned where content will load to avoid unexpected shifts in
>   positioning.

While it may seem like it only applies to screens shown at app launch, the guideline explicitly states: "This launch screen is appropriate for both app launches and **activity transitions within an app**."

Answer (score 0):

For initial loading, I would also apply using [launch screens](https://material.io/design/communication/launch-screen.html).

> Launch screens can be displayed upon an app’s launch from the home
>   screen when an app loads, instead of displaying a blank screen.
>   Displaying a launch screen can decrease the sense of a long load time,
>   and has the potential to add delight to the user experience.

However, according to material.io, in running applications, launch screens should not be used:

> Launch screens shouldn’t be displayed if an app is running.

For running applications, I think it is recommended to use [progress indicators](https://material.io/design/components/progress-indicators.html):

> Progress indicators express an unspecified wait time or display the
>   length of a process.

---

> ## Usage
>
> Progress indicators inform users about the status of ongoing
>   processes, such as loading an app, submitting a form, or saving
>   updates. They communicate an app’s state and indicate available
>   actions, such as whether users can navigate away from the current
>   screen.